# GCC options: warning on non-void functions without a return statement

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Is there a GCC/g++ option that generates an error/warning if there's a function that has a non-void return value, but doesn't contain a return statement in its definition?

E.g.:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    a+b;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`-Wreturn-type`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options).  It's enabled by `-Wall` (which you should always be running with, along with `-Werror -Wextra`).

Comment: +1: or maybe `-Wextra`, and based on personal preference, `-Werror`

Comment: To be honest, you should use all three of them to catch everything: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: @Griwes: Agreed.  I always build with these three at a minimum (although it still doesn't enable *everything*, which is annoying).

Comment: And, since this question is tagged C++, another very useful flag is `-Weffc++`.