# Not returning values, from a function with non-void return type

Tags: java, c++, function, return, return-value

I read [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936011/if-a-function-returns-no-value-with-a-valid-return-type-is-it-okay-to-for-the) how :

In C++ :

1. Not returning from a non-void function is undefined behavior.
2. `... analysis requires inspection of the entire program, which is incompatible with separate compilation, and which is not even possible in the general case ...`

From what I made out of several answers on that page, it is difficult, and infact impossible sometimes, to check the presence of a return statement in functions. That is not returning from a non-void function was left undefined behavior by the C++ standard.

However, I heard that in Java, the same thing is reported as an error at compile time.

Q. Is my understanding correct ? And how does Java achieves the same ?

---

Edit: Just to be clear, I am interested in understanding :

1. If it was left undefined in C++ standard for the implementation difficulties related to Compiler, how is Java able to achieve the same.
2. And if it is not that difficult to do, shouldn't C++ the standard have defined it as an error ?

Comment: It's not very hard to analyse this. A good C++ compiler will easily give you a warning if you don't return from a non-void function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does it by refusing to run some programs, even if they always return a value. Take the following (stupid) method

```
public boolean test() { 
   boolean var=true;
   if(var)
      return true;
}
```

The method always return true, but java will still refuse to accept it as valid. The same method in C++ would be legal because it always return a value.

So to sum up: Java will refuse your method, if the compiler can't prove that it always will return a value. This will sometimes reject methods which always does return a value.

C++ Just trust the programmer always to return a value, and then blows up at runtime if the programmer failed to return something.

Comment: That's a silly example, and certainly isn't a motivation for much of anything.  In this case, the entire function body would simply be `return true;`.  There are probably more complicated cases, but the most frequent case that occurs is when `test()` calls a function which doesn't return.

Comment: And of course, the real motivation for the difference is that it is always reasonably easy to provide a return statement in Java, even when you know that it will never be reached.  User defined types with value semantics mean that this is _not_ the case in C++; there are probably cases where it is almost impossible to provide a return statement.

Comment: The only case I have encountered where it was a problem in the real world, is when doing a switch on an enum where all values are handled, and all cases return. In that case you still need a default: or a return which will newer be reached.

Comment: I've encountered that too, but only in C++ (where it doesn't matter), and only in one case:`switch ( ch & 0xC0 )...`, with cases for `x00`, `0x40`, `0x80` and `0xC0`: the compiler didn't recognize that all of the possible cases were handled.  On the other hand, I've seen a lot of cases where functions in an interface weren't supported in some derived cases, and the derived function just threw an exception.  Indirectly, since all exceptions were being thrown through a function which logged them.

Answer (score 2):

All C++ compilers that I know of will report an error or warning if there is a code path that does not `return` from a non-void function.

As commenters point out, the reverse is *not* always true. The compiler may issue a warning in error because it is unable to correctly "understand" the code.

Comment: @JamesKanze - yes, it's not easy for the compiler to check that all code paths cover all situations. Is it possible? Is this akin to the Halting Problem?

Comment: @RogerRowland I quote : `Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined
behavior in a value-returning function
` . If Compilers could **always** achieve it, shouldnt the standard have defined it as an error ?

Comment: @AmitTomar If compilers could always achieve it, C++ probably would make it an error.  They can't.  Java requires a superfluous return statement in cases where they can't prove it.  (Java also requires more flow analysis than C++, so they can prove it more often.  But still not always.)

Comment: @RogerRowland I think it is equivalent to the halting problem.

Answer (score 2):

Java may require you to write code which can never be reached.
Consider something like:

```
void neverReturns() { throw SomeException(); }
MyType function()   { neverReturns();        }
```

It's clear that you can never fall off the end of `function()`,
but Java requires a return statement anyway.

There is a major difference in the languages, however, which
motivates the fact that C++ doesn't require a return statement.
Java has a very limited set of value objects (e.g. `int` or
`double`), all of which have easily constructed values (e.g. `0`
or `0.0`); everything else is a pointer (which will accept
`null`).  So you always have something simple to return in the
case where you know that it is irrelevant.  In C++, user defined
types can (and usually do) have value semantics, and very often,
don't have default constructors, or anything else you can easily
construct.  Imagine having to provide a return statement for
`function()` if the only non-copy constructor of `MyType`
required two or three arguments, all of them types which didn't
have value constructors either.  Where all Java would require
would be `return null;`.

Comment: Maybe it is just the wording but are you saying it is okay to not have a return in C++ for a value returning function?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Certainly.  There is undefined behavior _if_ you fall off the end of a function which should return a value.  As long as you don't fall off the end, for whatever reason (e.g. you called a function which threw an exception, or called `exit`), then there's no problem.  I've implemented hierarchies which only conditionally supported some functions; the unsupported functions simply threw an exception.  (This _isn't_ the best way to do this.  But I've used it, and I've seen it used.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes your understanding is correct. The way java does this is by being strict and
issuing errors even for methods that always return a value.

Suppose you have the following method. 
We know that it will always return a value because all cases are covered: a is either greater than zero or it is less than or equal to zero.
However java doesn't know this it sees an 'if' with a return, an 'else if' with a return but no 'else' and so no return, and hence will report an error.

```
int foo( int a ) {
  if ( a > 0 ) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if ( a <= 0 ) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

to fix the code for java need to remove the if from the else

```
int foo( int a ) {
  if ( a > 0 ) {
    return -1;
  }
  else /*if ( a <= 0 )*/ {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler just need to follow what [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) said:

> (8.4.7)If a method is declared to have a return type, then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).
>
> (14.1)However, certain events may prevent a statement from completing normally:
>
> 1.The break (§14.15), continue (§14.16), and return (§14.17) statements cause a transfer of control that may prevent normal completion of statements that contain them.
>
> 2.Evaluation of certain expressions may throw exceptions from the Java Virtual Machine (§15.6). An explicit throw (§14.18) statement also results in an exception. An exception causes a transfer of control that may prevent normal completion of statements.
>
> ......

Much more detail about *complete normally* is defined in JLS, especially §14.