# C++ omitting return type

Tags: c++

Here is my test code , I don't give the function a return value, but why this code can pass through the compiler? And I wonder if I don't give the explicit return type to one function like below, what the compiler will generate?

Here is the test code,Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
vector<vector<int> > testReturn(){
    int test = 5;
}
int main(){
    testReturn();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should enable compiler warnings/errors.

Comment: What compiler accepts this code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, according to [ideone](http://ideone.com/AeGoaL), gcc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot always trust the compiler as different compilers have different checking conditions while compiling. If you don't return in a function that need to return, even compiled successfully, the result is **undefined**. This is why your program crash. You should always try to avoid this.

Comment: (I believe) It is only undefined if you attempt to use the returned value (i.e., in the caller, e.g., `something = testReturn();`).

Answer (score 1):

This is an incorrect code, producing [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9936084/1732138).

Such code (function with return type bit without actual return statement) does compile in some variations with some compilers. This, however, means nothing but that there is a bug in the compiler, which should give a warning/error instead.

Comment: It is not a bug in the compiler. Standards allow compilers to deal with undefined behavior any way they like, including giving and not giving diagnostic messages.

Comment: On the standard side, you're right, but in most cases VS does show an error. So, at least for VS, it IS a bug

Answer (score 1):

> I don't give the function a return value,but why this code can pass through the compiler?

Providing a `return` value is optional in C. This rule "migrated" to C++ as well, adding to a long list of undefined behaviors (i.e. situations when invalid programs are allowed to compile). To C++'s credit, compilers do warn you about situations like this in rather unambiguous terms.

> And I am wonder if i don't give the explicit return type to one function like below, what's the compiler will generate the code?

The compiler will not generate any code for handling the return value. Whatever is the arbitrary state of the CPUs registers and the memory at the closing brace, that's the state that is going to be "returned". An attempt to interpret arbitrary values as the return value is what's going to cause the crash.

Comment: And, in particular, destroying the returned object at the end of `main` will probably do nasty things.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not compile as the return type of `testRunner` is a vector of a vector of ints.

So return it!

Comment: As strange as it sounds, Visual Studio also does not detect such problems from time to time, leading to crashes at runtime.

Comment: @DarkWanderer, VS doing something like this is not that strange :P

Comment: @DarkWanderer - Change the warning setting levels to the all.

Comment: @Ed Heal: well, undefined behavior having warning level 3 or 4 (?) is a really really bad idea. It must be an error or a W1, given the consequences.

Comment: @DarkWanderer - I do not understand why they have them in the first place. Get the compiler to fire up as many warnings as possible. That is my philosophy and has stood me in good stead