# partial type as template argument c++

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Simply, can I pass `std::vector` as a template argument. Following example list usage

```
tempate<typename container_t, typename value_t>
struct container_types
{
  typedef container_t<value_t> value_container_t;
  typedef container_t<pair<value_t> pair_container_t;

};
```

I wish to pass container_types to generate final two data types. 
If this is not feasible, then how can I achieve the same.

Comment: You *can* do it, but it's often not nearly as useful as you'd think. It's much better usually to pass in the actual types you want to use for your data members.

Comment: @juanchopanza: agreed that it is duplicate.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: possibly. but i go down this path and see how much trouble it creates. It would be useful in some scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <template<typename T> class container_t, typename value_t>
struct container_types
{
    typedef container_t<value_t> value_container_t;
    typedef container_t<std::pair<value_t,value_t > > pair_container_t;
};

template <typename T>
using my_vector = std::vector<T>;

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    container_types<my_vector,int>::value_container_t buff(100);
    std::cout << buff[50] << std::endl;
}
```

Note that I had to wrap `std::vector` with `my_vector`, as `std::vector` actually has several template arguments.

Comment: To keep using std::vector directly [you can use variadic template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21569318/51386).