# How Recursion works without extra return statement?

Tags: c++, c, recursion

Can someone explaine the result of this code below?
Here is the recursion function below.
The result should be:
`5*6*7*8*9*10 == 151200`
But the result shows
`4*5*6*7*8*9*10 == 604800`
Now where the 4 come from?
It would be better if you explain with recursion tree.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int fun(int a)
{
    if (a > 4)
    {
        return fun(a - 1) * a;
    }
}
int main()

{
    int x = fun(10);
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: what function `fun` returns when `a` is less than 4?

Comment: [Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-does-flowing-off-the-end-of-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-no)

Comment: What happens when you don't return anything from a function that promises to return non-void? BTW: Always compile with warnings enabled. The compiler would have told you that the code is brittle or even downright broken.

Comment: Make sure all branches in the function has a return statement. [If a function returns no value, with a valid return type, is it okay to for the compiler to return garbage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936011/if-a-function-returns-no-value-with-a-valid-return-type-is-it-okay-to-for-the)

Comment: Reaching the end of non-void function without a `return` is undefined behavior. Your compiler would've told you about it if you enabled the warnings.

Comment: @user12002570 The debugger would've shown weird values appearing out of thin air.

Comment: If `fun(4)` returns `4`, then you'd expect this result. Your current code may do something akin to `return a` for the cases not caught by your current code, which is why you should heed the other comments. This behavior is not standard nor expectable.

Comment: The fix is adding `return 1;` at the end of the fun() to eliminate the undefined behavior caused by failing to return a value in a non-void function: [https://ideone.com/OZBzpw](https://ideone.com/OZBzpw)

Answer (score 4):

It does not work. It is Undefined Behaviour and your program my behave any way.

```
<source>: In function 'fun':
<source>:15:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   15 | }
      | ^
```

Your compiler ***should*** warn you about it (it does not as you need to enable extra warnings, I would recommend `-Wall -Wextra` + `-Werror`) and you should have return statements on all function execution paths.

```
int fun(int a)
{
    if (a > 4)
    {
        return fun(a - 1) * a;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

> Now where the 4 come from? It would be better if you explain with
> recursion tree.

It is just an unspecified value as it is Undefined Behaviour and the value returned by the function can be everything.

For example, clang compiler generates code which prints ***`0`***

https://godbolt.org/z/z6nYY4rhf

gcc with -Os ***`4198464`***

https://godbolt.org/z/j7fEebPKP

Comment: It's opinion, but I really like having the base case listed first when doing recursion. It just mirrors the way I think about recursion better: `if (a <= 4) return 1;` then `return fun(a - 1) * a;`

Comment: @Chris everyone's brain works differently.

Comment: It's a good day when mine does. ;)