# what is the function return in term of argument n below is my code?

Tags: c, return-value

what is the function return in term of argument n? please hep me to understand?

```
unsigned int f(unisigned int n)  // function declaration
{

       // wht f function return in term of argument n?

 }
```

Comment: Q:  What is the function return [of a function that doesn't return anything]?  A: ["undefined behavior"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  A word which here very probably means "random garbage".

Comment: There is no return statement, so the behaviour is undefined. It will "return" stuff that was randomly put on the stack (mostly)... or crash.It crashes sometimes, which may suggest that the code works - very nasty bug.

Comment: That's why higher level languages REQUIRE a return value on all paths inside a function/method.

Answer (score 2):

If the calling code attempted to access the return value then it would be undefined behaviour:

However if the return value is never used then it is well-defined and nothing special happens. The compiler is not required to give a warning.

```
int main()
{
    foo(6);    // OK

    unsigned int foo = f(5);    // UB
}
```

It is a terrible idea to write code like this on purpose, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question isn't an exact duplicate of [Why does this C++ snippet compile (non-void function does not return a value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614282/why-does-this-c-snippet-compile-non-void-function-does-not-return-a-value), it contains an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20614325/3920237) by [Shafik Yaghmour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1708801/shafik-yaghmour):

> This is [undefined
>   behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) from the
>   [C++11 draft
>   standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf)
>   section `6.6.3` *The return statement* paragraph *2* which says:
>
> > [...] Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning
> >     function. [...]
>
> This means that the compiler is not obligated provide an error nor a
>   warning usually because it can be difficult to diagnose in all cases.
>   We can see this from the definition of *undefined behavior* in the
>   draft standard in section `1.3.24` which says:
>
> > [...]Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during
> >     translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic
> >     of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic
> >     message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance
> >     of a diagnostic message).[...]
>
> Although in this case we can get both `gcc` and `clang` to generate a
>   warning using the `-Wall` flag, which gives me a warning similar to
>   this:
>
> > warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

In theory, *anything* can arise from undefined behavior. In practice, you're likely to get a garbage result.