# C++ return statement not checked

Tags: c++, function, compilation, return, compiler-warnings

g++ 5.4.1 under Linux (UBUNTU 16.04) will compile the following 
program without errors or warnings:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string foo(){
    int a= 1;
    a++;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously the return statement in "foo()" is missing and the program
in my computer core-dumps. I am asking myself why the absence of the
return statement is not even warned at compilation time? Did I miss
something?

Comment: There's a reason you should always build with more warnings enabled. I always use at least `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` when building with GCC. Usually I also add `-Werror` to turn warnings into errors.

Comment: Compile your code with `-Wall`.

Comment: As for why extra compiler flags are needed, it's because the compiler doesn't have to produce a "diagnostic" (i.e. a message) about it, as per the C++ specification. It's still a very good thing to have, so the compiler added it as an extra flag that could be enabled.

Comment: @Ron In this simple case, yes. But you can easily extend the example so that the warning disappears again.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you didn't compile with warnings enabled.

Compile like this:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra main.cpp
```

and you should get:

> warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

PS: This is irrelevant to the version of GCC.

---

The compiler doesn't have to produce a diagnostic message, that's why warnings flags had to be enabled in order for the compiler to complain. Read more in [Why does this C++ snippet compile (non-void function does not return a value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614282/why-does-this-c-snippet-compile-non-void-function-does-not-return-a-value).

Answer (score 1):

You did not include the appropriate warning flags. Chances are you only used something like:

```
g++ source.cpp
```

Add:
`-Wall`, `-pedantic`, `-Wextra` and similar flags:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic source.cpp
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/720f501a9b6942fc)
That being said you should also include the `<string>` header:

```
#include <string>
```

and not rely on *free string rides* from `<iostream>`.