# "control reaches end of non-void function" produces error instead of warning

Tags: c, gcc, cime

I'm trying to compile a large project (https://github.com/ESCOMP/CTSM).  I would like to compile it as-is, without editing the code, if possible (it is known to build successfully on many platforms).

I'm using `gcc (SUSE Linux) 11.2.1`. and I get

> In function  ncmp : /run/media/dominic/hdbtrfs/dominic/git/ESCOMP/CTSM/cime/src/share/timing/gptl.c:4069:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]

from the following function.  I believe that earlier versions of gcc only gives a warning rather than an error in this instance.

```
/*
** ncmp: compares values of memory adresses pointed to by a pointer. for use with qsort
*/

static int ncmp( const void *pa, const void *pb )
{
  static const char *thisfunc = "GPTLsetoption";
  const char** x = (const char**)pa;
  const char** y = (const char**)pb;

  if( *x > *y )
    return 1;
  if( *x < *y )
    return -1;
  if( *x == *y )
    GPTLerror("%s: shared memory address between timers\n", thisfunc);
}
```

I expect this can be fixed by inserting a spurious `return` statement at the end of the function, but since I am interested to try to build an unmodified version of the code (I'm not currently a contributor on the project, so can't push changes upstream) I'm wondering if there's a workaround to convert this error to a warning using compiler flags?

As requested here is the gcc call that is genertaed by the makefile:

```
mpicc -c -I/run/media/dominic/hdbtrfs/dominic/git/ESCOMP
/CTSM/cime/src/share/timing  -std=gnu99 -O    -DCESMCOUPLED 
-DFORTRANUNDERSCORE -DNO_R16 -DCPRGNU  -DCESMCOUPLED  
-DFORTRANUNDERSCORE -DNO_R16 -DCPRGNU  -DNUOPC_INTERFACE 
-DHAVE_MPI /run/media/dominic/hdbtrfs/dominic/git/ESCOMP
/CTSM/cime/src/share/timing/gptl.c
```

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: Please see [gcc options: warning on non-void functions without a return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924570/gcc-options-warning-on-non-void-functions-without-a-return-statement)

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including removing the call to the undeclared `GPTLerror` if it is not needed and showing the command-line options passed to GCC. Per [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/f611dEaEW), GCC does not show any warning or error with its default options but does if `-Wall` is requested. But so does GCC 4.1.2, conflicting with your belief about earlier versions. So, are you using options that produce the warning with GCC 11.2.1 but not with 4.1.2? What are they?

Comment: "I would like to compile it as-is, without editing the code"  --> An option to quiet the warning-as-error for the selected .c file simple sets up for a future failing when someone does mis-edit something in the .c file and would have benefitted with the warning-as-error that is quieted.  Rather than [kick the can down the road](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kick_the_can_down_the_road), consider fixing code.

Comment: A better fix in the long term would be to declare `GPTLerror` with [`_Noreturn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Noreturn) (assuming that it indeed never returns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there's a workaround to convert this error to a warning using compiler flags?

I would expect the `-Wno-error` option to have that effect.  It should also be possible to narrow the scope of that to the specific diagnostic you report, but beware: there is no way with command-line options alone to narrow the effect to this particular instance of the issue.

**Addendum**

The question having been edited to show that the diagnostic category is `return-type`, I can say that one would use `-Wno-error=return-type` to make all diagnostics of this type warnings instead of errors.

Comment: Thanks - any idea how to "narrow scope to the specific diagnostic".  The [gnu reference page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html) does not seem to provide any info on how to use this flag.

Comment: @dww, the thing to recognize here is that prefixing a warning option with `no-` is a general facility, not documented on a per-option basis.  The full error message that you have now added to the question gives the needed information: the name of the diagnostic category involved is `return-type`.  Just as the docs specify that you can use the form `-Werror=n` to specify `-Werror` for specific diagnostics only, you can use `-Wno-error=n` to apply `-Wno-error` to specific diagnostics.  I will amend this answer.

Answer (score 2):

`-Werror` elevates all warnings to errors. You can reverse this for specific warnings with `-Wno-error=WarningName`, such as `-Wno-error=return-type`, as is clearly documented in [the GCC documentation for warning options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> This switch [`-Werror=`] takes a negative form, to be used to negate `-Werror` for specific warnings; for example `-Wno-error=switch` makes `-Wswitch` warnings not be errors, even when `-Werror` is in effect.